# Why does android has only one zram but linux distros use many zram equal to the number of cpu cores?

Tags: linux, kernel, ram, compression

Most android roms have only one zram device [zram0] but linux distros use many zram like zram0, zram1 ....
Why is it like that? Does using many zram consumes more power or adds complexity? what's the exact reason?

Comment: It's a debatable topic whether or not multiple ZRAM devices add any benefit. E.g. see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171950. Apart from that, you can create as many ZRAM devices as you want on Android too. Pass `zram.num_devices=<NUM>` parameter in kernel commandline. After boot do: `echo -n <SIZE> >/sys/block/zram[N]/disksize; mkswap /dev/block/zram[N]; swapon /dev/block/zram[N]`. That's all.